# What is a maximal entangled multipartite state?

Tags: entanglement, information-theory, terminology-and-notation

We know the four Bell states are the maximal entangled states for two-qubit states, and we know if a state cannot be written as the tensor product by its subsets, then it is a entangled state, so is there a definition of maximal entangled state?

Comment: are you asking specifically about maximal entanglement for multipartite states?

Comment: Yes, some description about maximal entanglement for multipartite states.

Answer (score 1):

A pure state is said to be maximally entangled if the Von Neumann Entropy $S(\rho_{A})$, where $\rho_{A}=Tr_{B}(\rho_{AB})$ is the maximum value. ie $S(\rho_{A})=log(d)$ where $d$ is the dimension of the subsystem $A$

Edit:
Just gonna add in here that, in the case of multipartite states, the entropy of the marginals in any bipartition of said state should be log(d), where $d$ in this case is the minimum over the dimensions of the systems involved in said bipartition.

Comment: What if three-qubit system (that is , multipartite system)?

Comment: You don't necessarily need subsystem B to be a single subsystem. What I am taking here are biparitions. A tripartite state would be maximally entangled if, upon tracing out any of the other 2 subsystems, the entropy of the remaining state in the subsystem that is left is log(d)

Comment: you might want to specify that this applies to *pure* states. Otherwise, the bipartite state $I\otimes I/dd'$ (with $d,d'$ dimensions of two spaces) also has "maximal entropy".

Comment: This is a good catch. I guess I just assumed that was what they were referring to given the only mentioned state was the bell states.